# Firestore Security Rules - Allow Public Create Access

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

A "send us feedback" button. I've tried `allow create;` as well as `allow read; allow create;`. Both fail and return "Insufficient privileges".

`allow write;` does work but allows delete.

Question: what does a Firestore security rule look like that will allow a public / unauthenticated user to write to a specific "feedback" collection? I want to limit access to this collection to create only. No list, no delete, no updating.

Here is a view of my rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
    }
    match /feedback/{document=**} {
      allow create;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my client side JS:

```
function submitFeedback(val){
    var newFeedbackRef = db.collection('feedback').doc();
    try {
        if(firebase.auth().currentUser){
            newFeedbackRef.set({
                message: val,
                created: Date.now(),
                sender: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
                senderEmail: firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
                senderUid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
            });            
        } else {
            newFeedbackRef.set({
                message: val,
                created: Date.now()
            });            
        }
        console.log("Got it. Thank you!");
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the entire rules that don't work the way you expect, not just a small snippet of what doesn't work.

Comment: it's `document=**` isn't it? so, do `{document}`...? ...yes. somebody is tee'd up for 25 pts.

Comment: @DougStevenson get this though: it appears that limiting what's created is only possible for `write`'s! i.e. I can't limit to 300 characters for `create`??? 
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request

Comment: What's the code you're running that creates a document and fails with those rules?  Again, please edit the question.

Comment: Well, I don't have a problem with java code that writes to a collection with those rules.  Not sure what's going on for you.

Comment: the issue is that I (think) I wanted to allow `.create` only, not `.write` (as `write` also allows `.delete`)